# How to prefill React Hook Form with setValue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying a simple form that has CRUD functionality.
When I click EDIT button It shows all the objects and it's fine.

editHandler func gets all things from this button:

```
<button
    onClick={() => editHandler(discount)}
    className='btn btn-info btn-sm'
    data-bs-placement='top'
    title='Edit Info'
    >
    <i className='fa fa-edit'></i>
</button>
```

When I console this function by passed the vlaues:

```
const editHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

This is the object consoled editHandler:

```
{
children: (3) ["Mahila", "Amira", "Badru-diin"]
date: "2020-11-22T10:49:32.296Z"
department: {_id: "5f8158396931c1c9cd164b54", name: "Inpatient"}
empId: "YH-A0184"
empName: "Abdulkadir Ahmed Mohamed"
fatherName: "Ahmed Mohamed Muuse"
hasChildren: true
husband: ""
isMale: true
isSingle: false
motherName: "Madina Ahmed Muse"
wives: [" Nuurto Abdi Ali"]
}
```

But when I use setValue is show only half of my objects if I click button I again it show again 70% and finilly if I click it show all:

THe finction is like this:

```
 const editHandler = (e) => {
    setValue('empId', e.empId)
    setValue('empName', e.empName)
    setValue('department', e.department._id)
    setValue('fatherName', e.fatherName)
    setValue('motherName', e.motherName)
    setValue('isSingle', e.isSingle)
    setValue('isMale', e.isMale)
    setValue('wives', e.wives)
    setValue('husband', e.husband)
    setValue('hasChildren', e.hasChildren)
    setValue('children', e.children)
    setEdit(true)
    console.log(watch())
  }
```

The consoled result from watch():

```
{
department: "5f8158396931c1c9cd164b54"
empId: "YH-A0184"
empName: "Abdulkadir Ahmed Mohamed"
fatherName: "Ahmed Mohamed Muuse"
isMale: true
isSingle: false
motherName: "Madina Ahmed Muse"
}
```

and there is dependent values like isSingle, which show husband or wife if it's false.

What I'm doing wrong. I'm new to react-hook-form.

Help.

I found something which is causing the issue is that the dependent checkboxes like show husband if !isSingle and !isMale.

but my issue still stands I need that dependent with working code.

Comment: I'm not clear about your code. What is your watch() function? Where did you declare your 'discount' and 'setValue'?

Comment: You know I imported setValue, watch with useForm:  `const { register, handleSubmit, errors, setValue, watch, reset } = useForm()`. and discount is gettting from database using ID like 1 person's information.

Comment: Well from what you you're saying it looks like you're stuck with the fundamentals of React. When you `setValue` it doesn't immediately affect the `value` variable, as it's asynchronous. 

Use a `useEffect(() => { console.log(value) }, [value]);` the callback inside useEffect will run only when the dependency array value changes, so FOR A FACT you know value has changed. Also, this won't work because `value` is an object, as the object won't change React won't detect changes. Look at `useMemo` hook. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Comment: The issue is not useEffect. Even if I console `watch()` only It skips the hidden inputs which are waiting `isSingle` to be false. The first time I click the button `isSingle` gets false and second time I click again the button, the hidden inputs gets their valvues.